# NonHttP response with jmeter spike testing

Tags: http, tcp, port, jmeter

im currently spike-testing a website. Ive setup a jmeter testplan so that it builds up 250 threads with a synchronizing timer, and then unleashes them all at once at a certain point. However for about half of the threads i keep getting a:

"Response code: Non HTTP response code: 
java.net.SocketException Response message: Non HTTP response message"

The response time on this message is often 0 ms, which leads me to believe it is a local issue.

Ive tried setting MaxUserPort and TcpTimedDelay in the registry settings, but to no avail.

Does anyone have any other suggestions on how to tackle this problem?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you're exceeding maximum connections limit of your Application Server or load balancer in front of it.

You can temporarily set `jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error` property to `true` either in

- `jmeter.properties` file - it lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation
- or specify it as an argument during JMeter execution as

  ```
  jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true -n -t yourscript.jmx -l yourscript.jtl
  ```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more details.

After test run inspect `yourscript.jtl` output to check error messages. It also worth checking application logs at this stage.